# How to manage versions of Data Model Schema versions

Tags: ios, core-data, schema, datamodel

I am having an app on app store. I have to update model version after every 2 months on average due to updates.

I have 7 versions right now and they will definitely increase in future.

[image]

I have some questions:

- How I can efficiently manage this
- Can I delete my older version?
- How many versions I can add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can efficiently manage this

I recommend naming the model versions based on the release they are associated with.  It helps to keep things straight.

> Can I delete my older version?

Yes but not recommended.  If someone is still using an older version of your app they will fail to migrate if the source is not there.

> How many versions I can add?

Unlimited.  However you should only have a version for each **production** release where data structure has changed.  If you have intermediate versions that only exist for development, I would recommend removing them as they don't impact the user.

Lastly, make sure you have a unit test that migrates from every old version to the current version.  Core Data is not temporal  and will not go from 1 to 2 to 3.  It only understands source and destination.  Can your app currently migrate from 1 to 10?  If not, you need to address that.

Answer (score 1):

**How I can efficiently manage this**

Continue to increase versions when you add changes to model.

**Can I delete my older version?**

Yes you can. Just open data model in finder and delete version, re-add data model to project. Also make sure you handle NSPersistentStore creation fail (if merge is unsuccessful).

**How many versions I can add?**

As many as you need.